# Set CGPath width to view width

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch

I am using `PocketSVG` for converting my `SVG` file to a `CGPath` like that:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        let myPath = PocketSVG.pathFromSVGFileNamed("CategoriesBar").takeUnretainedValue()

        let lineWidth: CGFloat = 3.0

        let insetRect = CGRectInset(bounds, lineWidth / 2.0, lineWidth / 2.0)
        let boundingRect = CGPathGetPathBoundingBox(myPath)
        let scale = insetRect.size.width / boundingRect.size.width
        var transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-boundingRect.origin.x * scale + insetRect.origin.x, -boundingRect.origin.y * scale + insetRect.origin.y), scale, scale)

        let transformedPath = CGPathCreateMutableCopyByTransformingPath(myPath, &transform)

        let myShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        myShapeLayer.path = transformedPath

        myShapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        myShapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        myShapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor

        self.layer.addSublayer(myShapeLayer)
    }
```

The problem is that the `myShapeLayer` is bigger the view and it being cut off the side, I want that the width of the path (I don't care about the height) to be equals to the view's width.

How can I do that?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure, but it looks to me that you're trying to use the width of the view to early. As I see your code is in the `awakeFromNib()` which gets called before the layout is set. The code that uses your view's bounds and width should be moved to `layoutSubviews()`  ... override func layoutSubviews() {...}. I might be wrong, but would appreciate if you'll let me know it this is useful.

Comment: @Andrej Yep, that was the problem, thanks!

Comment: @Andrej I have another small question, how can I snap the path to the bottom of the view instead of to the top? thanks!

Comment: Do you use AutoLayout? If that's the case you could set a constraint to pin your view to the bottom.

Comment: @Andrej My view is pinned to the bottom, but I want to pin the path to the bottom of the view (the is pinned to the bottom of the container), I'm sure I need to change something in the `transform` variable (in the code I added to the question), but what?

Comment: Aha, I understand now. But I don't know. Sorry.